# concatenate string and number using jinja2 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

> To concatenate strings and numbers in my python script ,now I use
>   string.format() as follows ,How can I use jinja2 for the same.

```
for item in mylist:
        mystr = '{}{}{}'.format(item['name'] + ' ;' + 
                ' ' + str(item['age'])+ ' ;'  if item.get('age') else ';',
                ' ' + item['email']+ ' ;' if item.get('email') else ';'                        
                )
```

some sample output of mystr are

```
 1. abc ; 25 ; abc@gmail.com
 2. cdf ;;;
```

I want to use jinja2 in my python script to format the string.How can I do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you can simplify your string `mystr = ';'.join((item.get('name',''),str(item.get('age','')),item.get('email','')))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
{{ item['name'] }};{{ item['age'] }};{{ item['email'] }};
```

This is because in Jinja2, if something is undefined, Jinja2 will insert "nothing".

I used the liberty to ignore your spaces distribution. If you need the spaces, then you can use Jinja2's [if-expressions](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#if-expression):

```
{{ "%s ;" % item['email'] if item['email'] is defined else ";" }}
```

Comment: am developing a python project not django template.then how to do?

Comment: Jisson, in your question you said "I want to use jinja2". What I've shown you is for Jinja2. Jinja2 is very similar to Django's templates, maybe that's the reason it's familiar to you, but it's not identical to django.

Comment: am completely new to jinja, how can I use  {{ }} in python code? it s sytax error, or I have to use jinja2.somemethod({{}})?

Comment: Hu?  If you want to do that in python code, then use YOUR example code. Or if you really asking how to call jinja2 from python, then have a look at http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#basics  ... also look at from_string().

Answer (score 1):

from jinja2 import Template

```
template = Template(
            "{{ name }} ;"
            "{{ ' 'if age }}{{age if age }}{{' 'if age}};"
            "{{ ' ' if email}};{{ email if email}}{{ ' ' if email}};")

for item in mylist:
    people_tag =template.render(
                    name= item['name'],
                    age = item.get('age'),
                    email= item.get('email'))
```

o/p

abc ; 25 ; abc@gmail.com;

xyz;;;